# PHP str_replace for nested single and double quotes

Tags: php, wordpress, string, replace

Hi I try to replace some code to load CSS async. I'm using

```
function js_composer_attributes( $html, $handle ) {
    if(strpos( $html, "js_composer.min.css" )) {
        return str_replace( " media='all'", " media='nope!' onload='this.media=\'all\''", $html );
    }
}
add_filter( 'style_loader_tag', 'js_composer_attributes', 10, 2 );
```

but it fails with an output like this:

```
<link ... type="text/css" media="nope!" onload="this.media=\" all\''>
```

I'm looking for

```
<link ... type="text/css" media="nope!" onload="this.media='all'">
```

Tested multiple variations with ' and " but never made it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using double quotes instead of those escaped single quotes at the end?

```
function js_composer_attributes( $html, $handle ) {
    if(strpos( $html, "js_composer.min.css" )) {
        return str_replace( " media='all'", " media='nope!' onload='this.media=\"all\"'", $html );
    }
}
```

Comment: yes it generates onload="this.media="all"" which isn't working with the onload

Answer (score 0):

You are not escaping the right quotes. This is what you are using:

```
    return str_replace( " media='all'", " media='nope!' onload='this.media=\'all\''", $html );
```

which will give you `media='nope!' onload='this.media='all''`

... note the nested single quotes around
`all`

If you make the quotes for `nope` and `this.media` double quotes and leave the quotes around `all` as single quotes like this:

```
return str_replace( " media='all'", " media=\"nope!\" onload=\"this.media='all'\"", $html );
```

...you should get `media="nope!" onload="this.media='all'"`

Comment: @Tobi I’d an typo in my code... I’ve fixed it now, in case you have tried the previous code!. This works as I’ve tested it.

Comment: @Tobi, did this work for you after I fixed the typo, or do you need more help?